# Database query to find users that share an IP Address

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL, I have a simple table that logs the IP Address that users login with:

```
TableIPLog
------------
ColumnID (primary key)
ColumnUserID (the ID of the user)
ColumnIP (the IP address the user used to login)
```

I want a query which will find the users which have shared an IP address!

To clarify, I want the query to only show rows where the IP Address has been used by more than 1 member.

I'm stumped.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Just use a simple self-join? (Where IP = same, User = different)

Comment: However, a -1 for not trying anything or, if something has been tried, not posting it as part of the question: this both shows effort and "gives guidance". (Remember that downvotes can be reverted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go this route, this is for SQL-Server, but I'm sure there is a mysql equivalent:

```
select ColumnIP, count(*)
from TableIPLog
group by ColumnIP
having count(*) > 1
```

Then you can use those ip's to look up the usernames associated with them...

Edit: Thinking about this, it may not work depending on your implementation of the log, but it wouldn't take much playing around with to get it to work... maybe using an exists clause...

Comment: This was enough to get me started, I'll use it as a subquery.

Comment: @soupagain Why use a sub-query again? Also, consider what the results of this would look like when the *same* user logs in from the *same* IP twice... suddenly it looks like square 1 again.

Comment: @pst this was my concern after thinking about it a little longer.  I like your solution of a self join, I think that'd end up a little better, and you could always sub-query from that if it came down to it...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id,a.userid,a.ip 
FROM ip_log a inner join ip_log b 
ON a.userid<>b.userid and a.ip=b.ip;
```

This would list out all the userid and ip with same ip but different userid.

Comment: Hoorah! I like it! (+1 Go on now, give yourself a name ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you store the IPs like this (please check [this link](http://daipratt.co.uk/mysql-store-ip-address/)):

```
mysql> SELECT INET_ATON('192.168.0.10') AS ipn;
+------------+
| ipn        |
+------------+
| 3232235530 |
+------------+

mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(3232235530) AS ipa;
+--------------+
| ipa          |
+--------------+
| 192.168.0.10 |
+--------------+
```

and to make the search should be like:

```
select INET_NTOA(columnIp), count(*) from tableIPLOG group by columnIp having count(*)>1
```

Comment: Yes, I'm storing the IPs as INTs and using INET_NTOA as you suggest.

Comment: So this shows where a particular IP is used more than once ... okay. However it doesn't solve the problem: "...only show rows where the IP Address has been used *by more than 1 member*." The same IP could be used by the same member multiple times. (The ColumnUserId is not a key.)